# Most appeared search between a particular time

Tags: search, count, apache-pig

I have a search log with fields namely time, place and the query. I want to find the most queried word from a particular place between a particular time. All the fields namely date,time, query_String are chararrays. I have the below pig script but it doesnot do what is required.

```
Data = LOAD 'data' USING CustomPigStorage();
FClients = FILTER Data BY NOT(country is null);
Clients = FOREACH FClients GENERATE date,time, country,query_string as query;
grp = group Clients by (query, country, date, time);
wth_count = foreach grp generate FLATTEN(group), COUNT(Clients) as count;
```

For example, I want the result to be "between 2pm and 3 pm, hello was searched 4 times from USA".
I am basically confused by the Count() function .Relatively new to pig. I believe my count() here is counting the total number of records I have.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks correct, COUNT(Clients) returns number of records in the bag, that came from Clients and belong to the group. To see it you can remove COUNT from "wth_count" statement and save results into a file and than look into it.

```
wth_count = foreach grp generate group, Clients;
store wth_count into 'path';
```

Your potential problem might be in the fact that you are using date and time columns in the group by and they produce too many groups. To mitigate this you could write a java static function that gets date and time and returns a single value for the range, for example 12-07-2012, 14.05.03 is converted into "12-07-2012 14h" and 12-07-2012, 14.05.05 into "12-07-2012 14h". This will create a key that covers the time interval 2pm and 3pm and will put all of the records from Clinets into that group's bag.

Comment: I want to group Clients according to query and later on want the count of the grouped queries. That is how many times each query was grouped.

Comment: Could you provide a sample input and expected output?

Comment: input: date, time, country, query
output: query, country, date, (time1, time 2.. timen), (no of times it appeared on the date)
basically group all the time on a day the query appeared and count the number of times the query appeared on a particular day
2012/3/1, 16:04:01, US, west 4 st
2012/3/1, 16:04:02, US, west 4 st

The output should look like:
west 4 st, US, 2012/3/1, (16:04:01, 18:04:02), 2